# How to increasing middle element text characters without effecting others elements

Tags: css

In list items have a link and span attibutes like below,

```
<li>
<span class="a">Icon 1</span>
<a href=" class="b">Title length Should be 180 charcters</a>
<span class="c">Icon 2</span>
</li>
```

Find below the screen shot ,

[image]

Comment: Try in Css: .c{margin-top:0px;}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `flex`

```css
li {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <span class="a">Icon 1</span>
    <a href="" class="b">Title length Should be 180 charcters Title length Should be 180 charcters Title length Should be 180 charcters </a>
    <span class="c">Icon 2</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Or `display: table`/`vertical-align: top`

```css
li {
  display: table;
}
li * {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <span class="a">Icon 1</span>
    <a href="" class="b">Title length Should be 180 charcters Title length Should be 180 charcters Title length Should be 180 charcters Title length Should be 180 charcters Title length Should be 180 charcters </a>
    <span class="c">Icon 2</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Or `display: inline-block`/`vertical-align: top`

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
li * {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  white-space: normal;
  width: 10%;
}
li a {
  width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <span class="a">Icon 1</span>
    <a href="" class="b">Title length Should be 180 charcters Title length Should be 180 charcters Title length Should be 180 charcters Title length Should be 180 charcters</a>
    <span class="c">Icon 2</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```